# uiautomatorviewer, ubuntu - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale$Builder.build()Lcom/ibm/icu/util/ULocale

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, appium

I installed `uiautomatorviewer` on `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` by command:

```
sudo apt-get install androidsdk-uiautomatorviewer
```

Then i typed:

```
uiautomatorviewer
```

And I saw error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale$Builder.build()Lcom/ibm/icu/util/ULocale;
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.addULocale(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:206)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.getLocales(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:140)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.ICULocaleServiceProvider.getAvailableLocales(ICULocaleServiceProvider.java:53)
    at com.ibm.icu.impl.javaspi.util.CurrencyNameProviderICU.getAvailableLocales(CurrencyNameProviderICU.java:39)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$CurrencyNameProviderDelegate.addImpl(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:485)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$CurrencyNameProviderDelegate.addImpl(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:479)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:97)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter$1.run(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:74)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.SPILocaleProviderAdapter.findInstalledProvider(SPILocaleProviderAdapter.java:74)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.AuxLocaleProviderAdapter.getLocaleServiceProvider(AuxLocaleProviderAdapter.java:70)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.<init>(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:133)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool.getPool(LocaleServiceProviderPool.java:111)
    at java.util.Currency.getSymbol(Currency.java:506)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:648)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:113)
    at sun.util.locale.provider.DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbolsProviderImpl.java:85)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(DecimalFormatSymbols.java:180)
    at java.util.Formatter.getZero(Formatter.java:2283)
    at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1892)
    at java.util.Formatter.<init>(Formatter.java:1914)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.checkAdbVersion(AndroidDebugBridge.java:583)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.<init>(AndroidDebugBridge.java:559)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge(AndroidDebugBridge.java:319)
    at com.android.uiautomator.DebugBridge.init(DebugBridge.java:68)
    at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:71)
```

How to fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```

and pasting in file /usr/bin/uiautomatorviewer the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/AndroidSDK/tools/bin
bash ./uiautomatorviewer
```

Where `~/AndroidSDK/tools/bin` is my path where uiautomatorviewer installed by Android Sdk is placed (my `$ANDROID_HOME` has value `~/AndroidSDK`).

Finally I make script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/uiautomatorviewer
```